# visualsvn error

Tags: svn, netbeans, visualsvn-server

I am using NetBeans IDE and VisualSVN 1.7. I get the following error.

```
Failed to execute WebDAV PROPPATCH
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: At least one property change failed; repository is unchanged
RA layer request failed
svn: Error setting property 'ignore': 
Could not execute PROPPATCH.
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 2):

It sound like your SVN client is trying to operate through a proxy that does not allow the use of proppatch verb.

Try configuring your SVN client to bypass your web proxy server or configuring your web proxy server to allow the use of all of the HTTP verbs for your SVN server.

Answer (score 1):

Please check end line character in svn property 'ignore'. Most clients normalize line endings, but it looks netbeans does not.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a proxy like one of the answers suggested, did you remember to put a pre-revprop-change.bat file in the directory of the proxy?  The contents should be at least

```
@exit 0
```

No  or  necessary.